# Http server - listening to responses

Tags: c#, http, service, request, listener

I have read the following article for creating a simple http service:
[Create a Simple Threaded HTTP Server with C#](http://www.prodigyproductionsllc.com/articles/programming/create-a-simple-threaded-http-server-with-c/)
Before implementing something, I'm in a bit of a dilemma.

I have a service sending http requests to multiple destinations (with a limit of max destinations simultaneously), and recieving a response from each of the destinations.
The response is short, only a status (200 if ok, or some other code) if the request was processed correctly or not.

The article above creates a listener in a while loop which is blocked and is listening for requests.

```
23          private static void Listen()
24          {
25              listener.Start();
26              WriteLog("Listening On: " + port.ToString());
27   
28              while (true)
29              {
30                  WriteLog("Waiting for connection...");
31                  TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
32                  Thread listenThread 
                       = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ListenThread));
33                  listenThread.Start(client);
34              }
35          }
```

I need to send requests to devices and listen for a response from each.
Is it possible that If I get one response, and till the loop returns to the listen command (31) another response will slip by?

If I have a limited amount of http requests being processed should I create a listener for each or one listener is better?

Comment: "Listen for the response"? Usually you issue a request and get the response. This is not a description of an HttpListener, but rather just a plain old http request. Why do both ends need to be listening? Are you saying that you hit the remote device, then it issues its own (separate) request back to you? Wouldn't it be better just to issue a response to the initiating request? Seems to me that at the very least there's some confusion about what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @spender I see. Might it be that I have not thought about it thoroughly. My aim is to send information to a long list of destinations. Each transmission of information can contain a small query request or a transmission of a file to the destination. I want to submit at once at most X number of transmissions simultaneously, and wait for a response. So a simple old plain request might be sufficient in my case?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you concider theT ASP.net Webapi ? This should dp exactly what you need :-)
There you can also have async controllers and there are tons of examples.

Answer (score 1):

TCP connections awaiting `accept` are put in the connection backlog (which is by default 100 IIRC, you can change that in your listener constructor). That means there can be 100 concurrent TCP connection requests waiting to be accepted.

So, unless you have more than that number of connections waiting to be processed, you won't lose any.